# Android: custom shape buttons

Tags: android, button

I need to create two buttons with sharp corners on the one side, that complement each other. Like this:
[image: Two buttons with sharp corner on the one side, that complement each other.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that come in mind:

use a "merge" instead of the classic FrameLayout and make your 2 buttons slightly overlap:
http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top.

Edit:
Do not forget to add drawables for the pressed, selected states and make sure the borders are well done, so the behaviour won't be too weird when selected/pressed.

Comment: Aligning the `Buttons` by the right border will not create the Button in the image.

Comment: Ok i realy can use images in relative layout and make them clickable and focusable and provide selectors for them. But how put tham together like two parts of one puzzle?

Comment: FrameLayout, sorry, was a typo look at: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

Comment: Thanks think overlap will work!

Answer (score -1):

Your best bit is to use a horizontal Linearlayout with image of both buttons and tow transparent views on top of it.

You will have to have something like this in your code:

xml layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity code:

```
    private LinearLayout mParent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    mParent = (LiearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    (findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(mListener);
    (findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(mListener);
     }
      private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener(){
       public onClick(View view){
         //change parent color
       }

   } }
```

Or even you can use onTouchListener to handle more precise events .

Comment: Would be horrible... Buttons would not react to click by changing colors. Also would be impossible to select them correctly and would create a crazy layout hierarchy!

Comment: You can easily use multiple drawable resources for all buttons states and apply them to the layout programatically on each state. 
And not sure what you mean by crezy layout hierarchy. since anyway he will have to use somekind of a group view with tow children in it

Comment: I uderstand all of this about making images clickable and focusable and provide selectors for them. But how put tham together like two parts of one puzzle?

Comment: As your buttons will have a transparent ovelay on the top, that means that there 3 views (1 big button and 2 transparent one at the top). When you click on the right button, how can you be sure that the right one will use the multiple drawable view? Use them on transparent resource?

Comment: @Waza_Be: you didn't understand my answer "and that explains the down vote", the touch events are handled by the transparent views . the parent is used to provide the graphical feedback .